# .How to get residuals time series for a Sarima model in R?

Tags: r, time-series

I wanted to perform Ljung-Box test on my model. Now when I use the Model= auto.arima() to have a model, it automatically saves residuals and I can simply use Model$residuals as a vector in my Box.test. But when I am trying a different model using Model = sarima() then Model$residuals is null and I don't know how to have Ljung-Box test on that

```
> library(forecast)
> AutoModel = auto.arima(A)
> library(astsa)
> Model1 = sarima(A, 1,0,3,0,1,1,12)
> Box.test(AutoModel$residuals, lag=20, type='Ljung-Box')
> Box.test(Model1$residuals, lag=20, type='Ljung-Box')
```

Box test of Automodel will give the answer but not of Model1

Comment: You need to use SO [edit] facilities to show code that includes `library` calls to load all necessary packages.

Comment: The values you want are in `Model$fit`. It's `resid(Model$fit)`.